# Set max value of max_connections in mysql but didn't

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know what is the max connection value of mysql max_connections

when i set mysql max connection value like

```
set global max_connections = 1000000;
```

and check for the set value it shows me

max_connections = 100000;

but i set it to 1000000

I am excited to know why this happens and how to solve this issue to get 1000000 value.

And I also would like to know that this type of such more connections does any performance issue

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max_connections` controls the number of *concurrent* connections you can have.  Most systems don't need more than 100.  Each connection takes some RAM, so asking for 1M or even 100K will chew up a lot of memory -- possibly causing the system to crash.  Don't set *that* variable *that* high.

There are two versions of the `VARIABLES` -- one `GLOBAL` and one `SESSION`.

When mysqld starts, the `GLOBAL` one are set from the config file(s) and/or defaults.

When a connection starts, it inherits the `GLOBAL` values for its `SESSION` values.  (I'll stop here since it is not relevant to your question -- but be aware of such if you stumble in some other direction.)

To answer your **specific question**, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections -- Note that the max value is only 100K.